# apache spark understanding dense vector

Tags: vector, apache-spark

My question is based upon code from [the page](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-guide.html).

my general understanding is that sparse vector is used when most of the elements are 0 and the dense vector is used when very few elements are 0.  A sparse vector is easy to compress

why do we have to define below vectors as dense vectors? How does defining dense vectors help given that there are only 3 elements in each vector. Why cannot we just refer them as vectors?

```
# Prepare training data from a list of (label, features) tuples.
training = sqlContext.createDataFrame([
    (1.0, Vectors.dense([0.0, 1.1, 0.1])),
    (0.0, Vectors.dense([2.0, 1.0, -1.0])),
    (0.0, Vectors.dense([2.0, 1.3, 1.0])),
    (1.0, Vectors.dense([0.0, 1.2, -0.5]))], ["label", "features"])
```

Comment: what you are asking is not clear. what is the issue ?

Comment: i am having hard time understanding why `Vectors.dense` has been used. why cannot we just say that the first element is  `(1,([0,1.11,0.1]))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark uses [breeze](https://github.com/scalanlp/breeze) under the hood for high performance Linear Algebra in Scala.

In Spark MLlib and ML some algorithms depends on `org.apache.spark.mllib.libalg.Vector` type which is rather dense or sparse.

Their is no implicit conversion between a scala Vector or array into a dense Vector from mllib.

Semanticaly speaking, Dense vectors are equivalent to normal vectors, as you see you can create them with mllib Vectors factory with the dense methods to create a Vector of type org.apache.spark.mllib.libalg.Vector